# Is there a Chrome extension to collapse blog comments?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

It's very frusterating when I encounter an article like [this](http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/04/01/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx) and 95% of the height is taken up by comments, with no option to collapse/hide them. Is there any Chrome extension that can do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://stevenf.com/shutup-css/

This is a custom stylesheet you can load into Chrome either as an extension or user stylesheet. Usually I use iReader in those situations, but it doesn't seem to work on that website. If that doesn't work, I'd try using the Google Mobilizer bookmarklet.